# php7.2 and PDO - 'could not find driver'

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

first of all:
System Ubuntu 16.04
Apache2
PHP 7.2
DB: MYSQL

now following problem:
I have two projects the first project is just a php file with the following code

```
<?php
$servername ='localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '12345';
$dbname = 'test';
try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   do stuff ...
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is working fine, I am able to connect to the database and get desired data.

Now I wanted to do it a little bit different:

```
<?php

class Database {
    // DB Params
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $db_name = "test";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "12345";
    private $conn;

    // DB Connect
    public function connect() {
        $this->conn = null;
        echo "connect() - ";
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('myqsl:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'HEY! Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Now here I get the following error:

> could not find driver

I am trying for hours to find a solution but with no success.
It works but not in a class ? ....

Comment: God dammit it was just a typo AHHHHHH 2 hours of my life wasted ... in the class it say myqsl instead of mysql -.-

Answer (score 0):

It was just a typo ... in the class it is

> myqsl

instead of

> mysql

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING!**
I fall in similar mistake when i try to break connection string in multiples lines and lost 2h also trying reinstall drivers and config:

```
define('DB_HOST',     'localhost');
define('DB_BASE',     'mydb');
define('DB_USER',     'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

try {
    $conn = new PDO('
    mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_BASE . ';charset=utf8mb4',
     DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    print 'Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

That throwns an PDOException: could not find driver.

The issue i found with connection string:
BREAK LINE + mysql:host...
is diferent from
mysql:host...

Solution: Just put the ' bellow like that then you not breaking the connection string:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_BASE . ';charset=utf8mb4',
     DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    print 'Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```